# Pig latin function giving wrong output

Tags: c, string

I am writing a function to convert a word to piglatin. However I am getting the wrong output and I am unsure what I am doing wrong. this is my code below. On some words it simply returns the original unaltered word. Maybe I am going about this the wrong way. I would appreciate some help.

```
char* convertToPigLatin(char* engStr, char* pLatinStr)
{
    int length = 0;
    char rSuffix[10];
    char vowels[6] = "aeiou";
    int i = 0;

    while (engStr[length] != '\0')
    {
        length++;
    }//setting int length equal to the length of the input string. 


    while (i < length)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            //checking if the lead character is a consonant
            if (engStr[0] != vowels[j])
            {
                rSuffix[j] =  '-';
                rSuffix[j+1] = engStr[0];

            }
            //checking if there is a string of consonants
            else if ((i != 0)&&(engStr[i] != vowels[j]))
            {
                rSuffix[j] = engStr[i];
            }
            //appending ay to consonant leading string
            else if (engStr[i] == vowels[j])
            {
                rSuffix[j] = 'a';
                rSuffix[j + 1] = 'y';
                rSuffix[j + 2] = '\0';

                strcat(engStr, rSuffix);
            }
            //string starting with vowel 
            else if (engStr[0] == vowels[j])
            {
                rSuffix[j] = '-';
                rSuffix[j + 1] = 'w';
                rSuffix[j + 2] = 'a';
                rSuffix[j + 3] = 'y';
                rSuffix[j + 4] = '\0';

                strcat(engStr, rSuffix);
            }

        }//for loop that goes thru the vowel array

        i++;
    }//while loop to go through the input string

    for (int k = 0; k < 25; k++)
    {
        pLatinStr[k] = engStr[k];
    }

    return pLatinStr;
}
```

this is for an assignment so the function header needs to be that way.

Comment: The for loop inside the while looks wrong to me: you're using j here both as an index into the vowels array, but also into rSuffix? Do you really need to loop through the whole of i checking for vowels? I thought it was just the first character. Can you explain the logic you're trying to implement in words please?

Comment: `while (engStr[length] != '\0')` - you can just do `int length = strlen(engStr);` and drop this loop.

Comment: @Rup well what I am trying to do is The while loop goes thru the word given to the function. The for loop serves as a check to see if a character in the string is a vowel or not. based on the for loop rSuffix will either be given the leading consonants and append ay to the end or it will append way if the word begins with a vowel..

Comment: And I appreciate you can't change it, but the problem with the function header is that it doesn't tell the function how large the pLatinStr buffer is. It looks like you're assuming it's 25 which is fine assuming callers know that they must always give your function a 25 char buffer, and that the result might not be zero-terminated if the input string is >24 chars long.

Comment: OK, but only the 'is this a vowel or not' needs to be inside the for(j = 0;j < 6;++j) loop. Only once you have completed that loop do you know if the character was a vowel or not. I'd change that loop to set an 'is vowel or not' flag and move the suffix generation logic outside that for loop. Or even drop the loop and just use `if ((c == 'a') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'i') || (c == 'o') || (c == 'u'))` to test if character c is a vowel or not.

Comment: And you don't need to loop over the whole string to compute the suffix: you can stop at the first vowel you find.

Comment: Do you think it would be easier if I made a separate function to check for vowels?

Comment: It doesn't really matter but it's worth a go - it would make this code slightly clearer. Assuming you have `bool`, that's just `bool isVowel(char c) { return (c == 'a') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'i') || (c == 'o') || (c == 'u'); }` (and assuming you're expecting lower case input only)

Comment: @bruno yes, I've just been busy with finals this week. I really appreciated your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot undertand your algorithm, mainly to know if you have vowel you have to compare a letter with all the possible vowel, not to do all your stuff for each possible vowel

Following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin and adding 'ay' at the end (not 'way' nor 'yay' etc) a possible way to do is :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* convertToPigLatin(char* engStr, char* pLatinStr)
{
  const char vowels[] = "aeiou";

  if (! engStr[0])
    /* empty string, not in pig latin def, decide to put ay */
    strcpy(pLatinStr, "ay");
  else if (strchr(vowels, engStr[0]) != NULL) {
    /* starts by a vowels */
    strcpy(pLatinStr, engStr);
    strcat(pLatinStr, "ay");
  }
  else {
    /* search first vowel */
    char * p = engStr + 1;

    while (*p && (strchr(vowels, *p) == NULL))
      p += 1;

    if (! *p)
      /* no vowel, not in pig latin def, decide to let word unchanged */
      strcpy(pLatinStr, engStr);
    else {
      size_t ln = strlen(p);

      strcpy(pLatinStr, p);
      strncpy(pLatinStr + ln, engStr, p - engStr);
      strcpy(pLatinStr + ln + (p  - engStr), "ay");
    }
  }

  return pLatinStr;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc == 2) {
    char * p = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 3);

    printf("'%s'\n", convertToPigLatin(argv[1], p));
    free(p);
  }
  else
    fprintf(stderr, "usage : %s <word>\n", *argv);

  return 0;
}
```

of course *convertToPigLatin* supposes the second argument is large enough

Compilation and executions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -Wall p.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out ste
'estay'
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out aze
'azeay'
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out mommy
'ommymay'
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out cf
'cf'
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out ""
'ay'
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```